# (index):889 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using Google Analyticator and my website is http://gestionalemagazzinoonline.it/

You can see the error in the javascript console.

I think that is the suspected file:
https://github.com/wp-plugins/google-analyticator/blob/master/google-analyticator.php

The problem is also if i disable the plugin, or if i change the source code i don't see the changes (maybe there's a cache?).

How can I fix?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: there is all the code to download: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/google-analyticator/

Answer (score 0):

Script tags are meant to write javascript in them, and not html.

You have a script block inside a script block. Remove that, and it will work all fine.

[image: Error]

Comment: there isn't a <script> tag into the file google-analyticator.php before "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)". if i change 'ga' with my name, i always see 'ga' in wordpress. I don't know why.

Comment: this is the file: https://github.com/wp-plugins/google-analyticator/blob/master/google-analyticator.php

Comment: I can't fix. If i remove something from that file, nothing changes, but i have only that "Analytics" plugin... I tried to remove the cache too. I also disabled the plugin, but I always see the analytics code????

Comment: @DavideCaballeros  I've no idea related to the plugin.